# All xxx have - plural vs singular

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I am very confused about which of the following two sentences is correct:

> All mugs have handles.

or

> All mugs have a handle.

Grammarly seems to accept both, but are they both okay?

Comment: Yes, they are. However, one means each mug has a handle and the other means each mug has more than one handle.

Answer (score 4):

They are both fine.

You could use the plural form if there is one or more each

> All dogs have legs

> All dogs have tails.

And you could use the singular form to emphasise that there is only one each

> All dogs have a tail